# Trying to perform form validation on my website

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

Followd a basic form validation video on youtube, and it seems that none of the messages on my javascript file are actually getting pushed onto the website with testing... Im expecting the error messages to display above the login form, but I could defintely have some errors in my code. any help would be appreciated.

```js
const username = document.getElementById('Username')
const password = document.getElementById('Password')
const form = document.getElementById('form')
const errorElement = document.getElementById('error')

form.addEventListener ('Login', (e) => {
    let messages =[]
    if (username.value === '' || username.value == null){
        messages.push('username is required')
    }
    if (password.value.length <= 6){
        messages.push('Password must be longer than 6 characters')
    }

    if (password.value.length >= 20){
        messages.push('Password is too long')
    }

    if (password.value == 'password'){
        messages.push('Password cant be password')
    }

    if (messages.length > 0){
        e.preventDefault()
        errorElement.innerText = messages.join(', ')

    }
})
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.main-head {
    height: 150px;
    background: #FFF;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #680C07;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.main {
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .login-form {
        margin-top: 10%;
    }

    .register-form {
        margin-top: 10%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .sidenav {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    .login-form {
        margin-top: 80%;
    }

    .register-form {
        margin-top: 20%;
    }
}

.login-main-text {
    margin-top: 20%;
    padding: 60px;
    color: #fff;
}

.login-main-text h2 {
    font-weight: 300;
}

.btn-black {
    background-color: #000 !important;
    color: #fff;
}

.login-form {
  margin-top: 20%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.alert {
    color: #31708F;
    background-color: #D9EDF7;
    border-color: #BCE8F1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="sitestyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script defer src="C:\Users\John\Downloads\capstone project\sitescript.js"></script>
    <title>Excell Visualizer</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div class="sidenav">
    <div class="login-main-text">
        <h2>Chartcel <br> Login Page </h2>
        <p>Login or register from here to upload your desired spreadsheet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="login-form">
                <form id="form">
                    <div id="error"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username"> Username </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" onclick="check(this.form)" class="btn btn-black">Login</button>
                    <button type="submit" onclick="check(this.form)" class="btn btn-secondary"> Register</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code is a bit of a mess. You add event listener for `Login` but that's not a standard Javascript event. There's also `onclick` but you didn't define a `check` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the line in your JS code to this:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
   // .... your logic
})
```

There is no 'login' event in the HTML DOM Events. So you should use 'submit'.